# Fixed div is doesn't ignore parent div width/height/position constraints

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm implementing a simple app with Vue.js and want to add a component that acts as a popup. What I usually do and has always worked for me, was to add a div with the following code into the css:

```
    .popupBg {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        z-index: 5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

This div acts as the overlay semi-transparent background and has another div nested inside of it that's the actual popup form container.

I've set up a clean new vuejs project yesterday and wanted to add one such popup with an overlay, but the fixed div stays contained inside on of one of its parent divs for some reason and not stretching over the entire html page.

App:
[image: Link to screenshot]

Html structure:

[image: Link to html structure screenshot]

The overlay is contained inside the div with class `traitGenerator container medium`, the overlay is the div `traitSelector popupBg`

I've done the same procedure many times in projects before but this one baffles me. Isn't the whole point of position: fixed that it ignores everything else in the DOM? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, I'd check if the parent div have a transform property set. - "It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to reproduce the problem with the entries you gave but it works like a charm, could you please give us the parent CSS ? (working usecase : https://jsfiddle.net/g0zkq6r4/2/)

Comment: Oh wow @CsabaFarkas thank you so much! I had transform on that parent div that was limiting the overlay and didn't know about this interaction. It works now.

Comment: @BadAyka happy to hear that. I added it as an answer so this might help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent div might have `transform` property set. Quote from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed):

> It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established
>   by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform,
>   perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see
>   the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the
>   containing block.